# How to update Pandas from Anaconda and is it possible to use eclipse with this last

Tags: python, eclipse, pandas

I have installed Python via Anaconda using the doc at http://www.kevinsheppard.com/images/0/09/Python_introduction.pdf and my Pandas version is 0.13.1.

However, since I presently have some issue with this version (no possibility to really calculate the mean using resample with DataFrame) I would like to know how I can quickly upgrade my version to 0.14.

I use to work with 'Python for Data Analysis from Wes McKinney' but I would like to know if it will not be worth to use eclipse for debugging (even if there are bugs with some eclipse version for the installation of PyDev) and how I can use it jointly with anaconda without any conflict.

Answer (score 69):

Simply type `conda update pandas` in your preferred shell (on Windows, use cmd; if Anaconda is not added to your PATH use the Anaconda prompt). You can of course use Eclipse together with Anaconda, but you need to specify the Python-Path (the one in the Anaconda-Directory). 
See this [document](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration.html) for a detailed instruction.

Answer (score 26):

The answer above did not work for me (python 3.6, Anaconda, pandas 0.20.3). It worked with

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas
```

Unfortunately I do not know how to help with Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

What I allways do to update to specific version is

- Activate environment
- `conda update pandas==0.14.0`

This might be do to conda recent updates

Answer (score -5):

try

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade pandas
```

Comment: I don't believe this answer is applicable. I believe the question is around using `Anaconda` whereas this is an answer using `pip`

Comment: Using multiple package managers in parallel is not a good idea. See anaconda's "Using Pip in a Conda Environment"
https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/

Comment: This answer should be deleted because it is not a legitimate attempt to answer the question in the OP, which is how to update with conda.