# Pandas in python 2.7 for ArcGIS

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, arcpy

I have found that pandas v13.0 for Python 2.7 win32 works for most codes I have written in which I want to use both arcpy and pandas. I put that pandas version into the C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages directory. I tried other versions, but got miscellaneous errors when trying to run them.

I wrote a new code today, however, that manages to not work. It gives the error:

> Access violation at address 1E0ACF39 in module 'python27.dll'. Read of
>   address 9807D3AF.

with the following code:

```
cond = dfDSS['OBSERVATION NAME']=='A413011CC1'
dfDSS['GROUP'][cond]='HA273UTheads'
```

All the code before this to create dfDSS using `pd.read_csv` and inserting the column 'GROUP' with a value of 'other' everywhere is fine. Only when I try to reset the values using the conditional statement.

The code to this point was written in iPython Notebook using Anaconda, but I now want to do some arcpy stuff with it.

Any suggestions in getting the different versions of Python to work together are appreciated.

Comment: If you have anaconda installed why not just upgrade using `conda update pandas`? See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840449/how-to-update-pandas-from-anaconda-and-is-it-possible-to-use-eclipse-with-this-l

Comment: @EdChum. I don't understand how that will help. The newer versions pandas don't seem compatible with ESRI python.

Comment: Well I don't know anything about arcGIS but if this was a maintained library it should hopefully be compatible with the latest pandas or at least newer versions

Comment: Thinking that ipython notebook is using a different, likely newer, version of both python and pandas than what you're using when running w/ESRI python.