# Calculate the difference of list elements if more than one element in the list is not zero

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, metadata

have a data set which looks like this:

```
Date       Item        A.unit       B.Unit    C.Unit      D.Unit   
10/11       A,D          5            0         0          12
11/11       A,B,C       10            10        5          0
12/11       A           20             0        0           0
```

i want the output column so that whenever there are more than one element in the list, it will calculate the difference of the unit, and when single element is present it will display zero.
so output will be:

```
Date       Item        A.unit       B.Unit    C.Unit      D.Unit          output
    10/11       A,D          5            0         0          12           5-12=-7 
    11/11       A,B,C       10            10        5          0            10-10-5=-5
    12/11       A           20             0        0           0            0--since only one element is there
```

can anyone please tell me how to get the output column.

Comment: There always are 0 for values if values not in `Item` per rows?

Answer (score 0):

Solution working with no check `Item` column - it use first non 0 value per `Unit` columns and subtract by sum of values, also if only 1 value it set `0`:

```
#all columns without first and second
df1 = df.iloc[:, 2:].mask(lambda x: x==0)
#alternative
#all columns with Unit in column names
#df1 = df.filter(like='Unit').mask(lambda x: x==0)
first = df1.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
df['output'] = np.where(df1.count(axis=1) == 1, 0, first - df1.sum(axis=1) + first)
print (df)
    Date   Item  A.Unit  B.Unit  C.Unit  D.Unit  output
0  10/11    A,D       5       0       0      12    -7.0
1  11/11  A,B,C      10      10       5       0    -5.0
2  12/11      A      20       0       0       0     0.0
```

---

Solution with match by `Item` column - explode `Item` to rows, multiple by `-1` and `0` if only one value and last aggregate `sum`, `first` and `join`:

```
df = df.assign(Item = df['Item'].str.split(',')).explode('Item').reset_index(drop=True)
df['new'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['Item'] + '.Unit')

df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['Date']), 'new'] *=  -1
df.loc[~df.duplicated(subset=['Date'], keep=False), 'new'] =  0


d1 = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['Date','Item','new']), 'first')
fin = {**{'Item':','.join}, **d1, **{'new':'sum'}}
df = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False).agg(fin)

print (df)
    Date   Item  A.Unit  B.Unit  C.Unit  D.Unit  new
0  10/11    A,D       5       0       0      12   -7
1  11/11  A,B,C      10      10       5       0   -5
2  12/11      A      20       0       0       0    0
```

Comment: Which package do we need to import for explode?

Comment: @SinghSonu - only upgrade pandas to 0.25+

Comment: i am using jupyter notebook

Comment: @SinghSonu - added new simplier solution, can you check it?

Comment: for Explode which module do i need to import i am running the code in jupyter notebook -jezrael

Comment: @SinghSonu - for explode is necessary upgrade pandas, try in conda cmd `conda update pandas` for last version

Comment: @SinghSonu - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840449/how-to-update-pandas-from-anaconda-and-is-it-possible-to-use-eclipse-with-this-l)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. The first step is to create a function that does exactly what you want on one specific row:

```
from functool import reduce
def sum_function(x):
  if len(x[x != 0]) == 1:
    return 0
  else:
    return reduce(lambda a,b: a-b, x)
```

If there is only one element in the row that is not 0, then return 0. If there are more elements then subtract them all. And here is how you can apply that function to every row:

```
columns = ['A.unit', 'B.unit', 'C.unit', 'D.unit']
df.apply(lambda x: sum_function(x[columns]), axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
0   -7
1   -5
2    0
```

And you could add that as a new column:

```
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum_function(x[columns]), axis=1)
```

Comment: What if i have more than 4 columns say 15 columns? what will be the change   columns = ['A.unit', 'B.unit', 'C.unit', 'D.unit']
df.apply(lambda x: sum_function(x[columns]), axis=1) in this

Comment: Yes just change `columns` to the columns you need. For example if all the columns you need have 'Unit' in it, you could use: `columns = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Unit')]` instead of listing them all by hand.

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'", 'occurred at index 0').getting this error while executing @L3n95

Comment: @SinghSonu At executing what? Are your "numbers" strings actually?

Comment: No they are int-L3n95

Comment: @SinghSonu in which line does it fail? Try `reduce(lambda a,b: int(a)-int(b), x)` If that works, then one of your numbers is a `str` and not a `int`

Comment: df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum_function(x[columns]), axis=1)  failing in this line-L3n95

Comment: in which line i have to apply reduce(lambda a,b: int(a)-int(b), x)? - L3n95

Comment: @SinghSonu replace the `return reduce(lambda a,b: a-b, x)` with `return reduce(lambda a,b: int(a)-int(b), x)`

Comment: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A '", 'occurred at index 0')-getting this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202722/discussion-between-l3n95-and-singh-sonu).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def calc(row):
    out = row[np.argmax(np.array(row.tolist()) > 0)]
    for c in row.values[np.argmax(np.array(row.tolist()) > 0)+1:]:
        out -= c
    if out == row.sum():
        return 0
    else:
        return out

df['output'] = df.drop(['Date','Item'], axis=1).apply(calc, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Date   Item  A.unit  B.Unit  C.Unit  D.Unit  output
0  10/11    A,D       5       0       0      12      -7
1  11/11  A,B,C      10      10       5       0      -5
2  12/11      A      20       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: @jezrael yes you are right, I edited my answer. thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `lambda, regex` is

```
unit_columns = list(df.columns[2:])
regex = re.compile(re.escape('.Unit'), re.IGNORECASE)
unit_columns_replaced = [regex.sub('', a) for a in unit_columns]

def output(row):
    ItemN = row['Item'].split(",")
    if len(ItemN) < 2:
        return 0
    idxs = np.where(np.in1d(unit_columns_replaced, ItemN))[0]
    c_names = [unit_columns[idx] for idx in idxs]
    f_columns = row.filter(items=c_names)
    return 2 * f_columns[0] - f_columns.sum()


df['output'] = df.apply(lambda row: output(row), axis=1)
df
```

which gives output as

```
    Date    Item    A.unit  B.Unit  C.Unit  D.Unit  output
0   10/11   A,D     5   0   0   12  -7
1   11/11   A,B,C   10  10  5   0   -5
2   12/11   A   20  0   0   0   0
```