# Pivot_table from lists in a column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe like:

```
    ID       Sim        Items          
    1        0.345      [7,7]            
    2        0.604      [2,7,3,8,5]      
    3        0.082      [9,1,9,1]
```

I want to form a `pivot_table` by:

```
df.pivot_table(index ="ID" , columns = "Items", values="Sim")
```

To do that,
I have to extract list elements in `items` column and repeat the `ID`,`Sim` values for each unique elements in row_list.
To be as:

```
    ID       Sim        Items          
    1        0.345        7  

    2        0.604        2 
    2        0.604        7  
    2        0.604        3  
    2        0.604        8  
    2        0.604        5

    3        0.082        9
    3        0.082        1
```

pivot table :

```
         7       2       3       8      5      1      9

    1  0.345     -       -       -      -      -      -
    2  0.604   0.604   0.604   0.604   0.604
    3    -      -        -       -     -     0.082  0.082
```

Is there any pythonic approach for that? Or any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use explode(*new in pandas 0.25+*) before pivot;

```
df.explode('Items').pivot_table(index ="ID" , columns = "Items", values="Sim")
```

---

```
Items      1      2      3      5      7      8      9
ID                                                    
1        NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  0.345    NaN    NaN
2        NaN  0.604  0.604  0.604  0.604  0.604    NaN
3      0.082    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  0.082
```

for lower versions of pandas, you can try with:

```
(df.drop('Items',1).join(pd.DataFrame(df['Items'].tolist())
 .stack(dropna=False).droplevel(1).rename('Items'))
  .pivot_table(index ="ID" , columns = "Items", values="Sim"))
```

---

```
Items      1      2      3      5      7      8      9
ID                                                    
1        NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  0.345    NaN    NaN
2        NaN  0.604  0.604  0.604  0.604  0.604    NaN
3      0.082    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  0.082
```

If exact ordering matters , use reindex with unique of Items after explode:

```
(df.explode('Items').pivot_table(index ="ID" , columns = "Items", values="Sim")
       .reindex(df.explode('Items')['Items'].unique(),axis=1))
```

---

```
Items      7      2      3      8      5      9      1
ID                                                    
1      0.345    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2      0.604  0.604  0.604  0.604  0.604    NaN    NaN
3        NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  0.082  0.082
```

Comment: pandas version 0.24.2

Comment: @nucsit026 I added a sample for pandas lower versions , if possible please [upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840449/how-to-update-pandas-from-anaconda-and-is-it-possible-to-use-eclipse-with-this-l) the version to access some cool features :)

Comment: @anky-91 It result: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

Comment: @nucsit026 cannot replicate that, it works fine for me, as said is it possoble to upgrade and try?

Comment: @anky-91 Thanks again I will try.

Comment: @nucsit026 check the edit for pandas lower versions, hope it works