# Pandas function to_numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

From pandas documentation, I found the function `to_numpy`
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html
But when I tried it(the same example as in the documentation), I have:
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'.

Do you know from where could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please share a minimal reproducible example so we can help with your issue. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `to_numpy()` was introduced in Pandas 0.24. On earlier versions, you need to call `df.values`.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `to_numpy()` was released with pandas version [`0.24.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html). Please upgrade your pandas package to use this attribute.

To check the version of pandas within your IDE:

```
import pandas
print(pandas.__version__)
```

You may refer [this link for upgrading `pandas`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840449/how-to-update-pandas-from-anaconda-and-is-it-possible-to-use-eclipse-with-this-l).